# Android SearchView with custom suggestions adapter

Tags: android, sqlite, searchview

I have a SearchView with a SimpleCursorAdapter, which queries suggestions from a SQLite DB. The query works just fine and the SearchView pops up a list with suggestions. However the suggestions are not visible. For example, if there are two suggestions, one can see that there are two list entries, but the text is not displayed. The SearchView is contained in a DialogFragment.

This is the initialization of the cursor adapter and the search view:

```
suggestionAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            null,
            new String[]{"name"},
            new int[]{android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1},
            0);

final SearchView searchProd = (SearchView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.searchProd);
searchProd.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
searchProd.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
searchProd.setSuggestionsAdapter(suggestionAdapter);
```

Search suggestions are generated in onQueryTextChanged, where the new cursor is generated and injected to the suggestionsAdapter:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    String[] columns = new String[]{"_id", "name"};
    String selection = "name LIKE ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{newText + "%"};
    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME,
            columns,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null);
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        suggestionAdapter.changeCursor(c);
        suggestionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: your code help me alot, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the adapter will show data with column names such as SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1. This is the column displayed in the search dropdown box. But your cursor uses the database column name *name" iin your case. So what you have to do is tell the adapter to match your database column with your adapter column. The way that I do this is create a HashMap with something like hashMap.put(name, name + " as " SearcgManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1) then in SQLiteBuilder mSqliteBuilder yoou can do mSqliteBuilder.setProjectionMap(hashMap) prior to creating your cursor. I don't use the onQueryTextChange for search suggestions but use contentprovider along with searchable configuration file. But because the columns are not matched is whyI believe you are not seeing your suggestions in your list

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you provided a layout for the `to` field in the constructor for `SimpleCursorAdapter()`. You should instead provide a resource ID for a textview, such as `android.R.id.text1`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It turned out that all I needed to do is to change the color of the text that is displayed in the listed entries. So I have it something like

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF2FF"
        />
```